# CS50 pset5 Speller - :( program is free of memory errors valgrind tests failed; see log for more information

Tags: c, valgrind, cs50

I get:

```
112 bytes in 2 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1: 
(file: dictionary.c, line: 112)
line: 112:  node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

This is my code:

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        unload();
        return 1;
    
    char word [LENGTH + 1];
    int coun = 0;

    while (fscanf(f, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            unload();
            return 0;
        }

        strcpy(n->word, word);
        n->next = NULL;
        coun ++;
        
        int index = hash(n -> word);
        n -> next = table[index];
        table[index] = n;
    }
    words_size = coun;
    fclose(f);
    return 1;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no `free` in this code, so there is obviously no way this code is intended to release memory allocated with the suspected `malloc`. Whatever code you chose *not* to post that is responsible for managing (either by rearrangement or disposal) your hash table has that burden, and should be included as part of a proper [mcve]. The fact the memory is reported as still-reachable suggests your simply not cleaning up your hash table prior to program exit.

Comment: WHich line is 112?  Please don't leave out such important details

Comment: OT:  regarding: `return 0;`  In general, a return of 0 indicates success.  Suggest returning -1

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  How do you expect us to help you debug the problem if we cannot reproduce the problem?

Comment: Regarding the return values, `false` and `true` would be better. You need to show us the code that tries to release the memory associated with `table`, which I presume is a static or global.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.